# Is it possible to feed the Soundcloud widget a list of song track IDs?

Tags: soundcloud

Is it possible to feed the Soundcloud widget a list/array of song IDs, or do I need to listen for specific events and load them in that way?

Answer (score 0):

sure, you can.

next time, pls come up with code.

docs:
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget

playground:
https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html

(i guess in the playground example you will find a list example, favs from user with id 1539950)